# MySQL localhost slow connection on IIS 8

Tags: mysql, php, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I already had this issue on my Windows 2008 Server and I was able to solve it the following way:

- Add 127.0.0.1 localhost to Windows hosts file
- Add skip-name-resolve to my.ini

It's very weird that on Windows Server 2012 (IIS8) these tricks don't help.

Creating a connection using PHP/MySQLi to MySQL needs 1 seconds when using localhost as server name, to 127.0.0.1 it needs 0.0001 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like it's querying your DNS server for the hostname anyway (although the hosts entry should prevent that). Try logging DNS lookups to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\DisabledComponents DWORD (32-bits) in your registry to the value 0x20 and then reboot the computer to prefer ipv4 above ipv6 (Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852)

Comment: Silly me, I should have known that... lol. Thank you for showing me that, I will try it out.